# Refactoring methods that share similar code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, lambda, refactoring

I have 6 methods in a helper that share very similar code:

```
module CategoriesHelper

  def item_count(category)
    items = []
    category.items.each do |item|
      if !item.completed
        items << item
      end
    end
    items.count
  end

  def total_items
    items = []
    @user.items.each do |item|
      if !item.completed && !item.content.nil?
        items << item
      end
    end
    items.count
  end

  def overdue_items
    items = []
    @user.items.each do |item|
      if (!item.completed && item.deadline_date &&
          item.deadline_date < Time.now)
        items << item
      end
    end
    items.count
  end

  def week_items
    items = []
    @user.items.each do |item|
      if (!item.completed && item.deadline_date &&
         item.deadline_date - Time.now < 7.days)
        items << item
      end
    end
    items.count
  end

  def today_items
    items = []
    @user.items.each do |item|
      if (!item.completed && item.deadline_date &&
         item.deadline_date.today?)
        items << item
      end
    end
    items.count
  end

  def completed_items(category)
    items = []
    category.items.each do |item|
      if item.completed == true
        items << item
      end
    end
    items.count
  end
end
```

I was wondering if there was any way of refactoring this as it seems to violate the DRY principle quite heavily. The only thing that varies in each one is the if statement and whether @user or category is used. I've tried putting a lambda in for the iteration:

```
Iterator = ->(object, if_statement) do
  object.items.each do |item|
    if if_statement
      items << item
    end
  end
  items.count
end

Iterator.call(@user, !item.completed && !item.content.nil?)
```

but that doesn't work as the if statement contains 'item', so when I try to call the lambda it doesn't recognise item as it hasn't been defined yet. Is there any way of defining items as an empty array in all of the methods in one go?

Comment: You're trying to re-invent AR here. This kind of logic does not belong in a helper, but in a model. Use scopes, Luke. With that you will be able to pull the items you need using simple user.overdue_items or user.total_items, etc.